# Circle with a center mark and legend label in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

I'm trying to draw a circle in pgf plot with a + mark at its center. right now I have this code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \begin{axis}[enlargelimits,
            xmin=-2,xmax=1,
            ymin=-1,ymax=1,
            grid=major,
        ]
            \draw [blue] (-1,0) circle [radius=1];
            % \label{l:circle}
            
            \addplot [only marks, mark=+, thick, forget plot] coordinates { (-1,0) };
        \end{axis}
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which sort of works, although I'm not sure using `addplot` for the center mark is a good idea, but drawing '+' marks with just tikz appears to be uneccessarily complicated. More importantly however, I cannot reference the circle line using `\ref{l:circle}` because the circle was not created using `addplot`. How can this be worked around?

---

I suppose the legend label issue can be resolved by using a parametric plot of a circle usign `addplot` as in the pgfplot example gallery:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}

            \begin{axis}[enlargelimits,
                xmin=-2,xmax=0,
                ymin=-1,ymax=1,
                grid=major,
            ]
                \draw [blue] (-1,0) circle [radius=1];
                % \label{l:circle}
                \addplot[samples=100, domain=0:2*pi, red] ({0.5*cos(deg(x)) - 1}, {0.5*sin(deg(x))});
                \label{l:small_circle}
                
                \addplot [only marks, mark=+, thick, forget plot] coordinates { (-1,0) };
                \label{l:center_mark}
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{I can reference (\ref{l:center_mark}) and (\ref{l:small_circle}) but not the blue circle.}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: Demo]

I still wonder about more clean ways of adding center marks.

Comment: Please add the missing lines so your code will compile when we copy it. Thank youo

Comment: Why are you using pgfplots at all? You could draw what you want in Tikz, too. What do you want to achieve in the end?

Comment: @MS-SPO I have updated a preamble for the example and commented the problematic line (`\label...`). I'm using pgfplots because my other plots use it as well and I want to use its legend feature. Drawing a simple '+' in tiky, e.g. with pics, was really annoying to get working properly. I want to achieve the plot that I have now but also be able to reference the line from within the text with a label.

Comment: Thank you. // Still don't get the reference you want to make. IF it was text, wou could reference it with a hyperlink. IF it's an executed plot I'm not aware you could retrieve its memory and execute it again, so to say: that path has been finished and rendered. May be it's a good idea to add a sketch (mock-up) of what your final result should look like to your question? (And a screenshot of your current result, too.)

Comment: @MS-SPO I have extended the example. The plot label / reference is a pretty basic feature in pgfplots. Ultimately the parametric plot works, but I think it would be cleaner if the center mark could be directly linked to the circle plot.

Comment: Ok, now I see the section in the manual: https://tikz.dev/pgfplots/reference-axisdescription#sec-4.9.6 . Ok, it's available, and, at least to me, pretty useless, once you provide a legend ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Labels and references with `pgfplot` need a `\addplot` command. Simply add `tikz` path operations after `\addplot`

```tex
\addplot [forget plot, blue] (-1,0) circle [radius=1];
\label{l:circle}
```

Full example:

```tex
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}

            \begin{axis}[enlargelimits,
                xmin=-2,xmax=0,
                ymin=-1,ymax=1,
                grid=major,
                ]

                \addplot [forget plot, blue] (-1,0) circle [radius=1];
                \label{l:circle}

                \addplot[samples=100, domain=0:2*pi, red] ({0.5*cos(deg(x)) - 1}, {0.5*sin(deg(x))});
                \label{l:small_circle}

                \addplot [only marks, mark=+, thick, forget plot] coordinates { (-1,0) };
                \label{l:center_mark}
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{I can reference (\ref{l:center_mark}) and
          (\ref{l:small_circle}) and the blue circle (\ref{l:circle}).}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: reference to the blue circle]